# Shree Ganesha and Sweet Dumplings (मोदक)?

Tags: scripture, puranas, ganesha

Why Shree Ganesha  Or Shree Ganapati likes **Sweet Dumplings or Modaka (मोदक)** so much.?

Which are the sanskrit Scriptures from Puranas denoting this favourite food of Shree Ganesha?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ganapati Atharvashirsa](http://www.greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/sri_ganesha-ganapati_atharvashirsha.php) (गणपति   अथर्वशीर्ष) is a minor Upanishad from the Atharvaveda.It extolls Lord Ganesh as Absolute Reality.

The mantra mention

यो मोदकसहस्रेण यजति स वाञ्छितफलमवाप्नोति ॥१६.४॥

He who worships (Ganapati) with thousand Modakas (a type of Sweetmeat), he will obtain his Desired Fruits.

Adi Sankar in his famous work Ganesha Panchratanam opens with following line,

मुदाकरात्तमोदकं सदा विमुक्तिसाधकं

Who Holds the Divine Joy in His Hand as Modaka (a sweetmeat) and Who Always strives to Accomplish the Liberation of His Devotees towards that Divine Joy

In Ashtottara Shatanamavali, Lord Ganesha is described as,

मोदकप्रियाय means one who loves modaka

Comment: Nice Answer, you also can provide any stories about" why Modakas and Sweetballs are Ganesha's  favourite. :)

Answer (score 2):

Lord Ganesha's favourite food is **Sweet Dumplings or Modaka.** Hindu's offer Modakas to Shree Ganesha as Neveydyam (नैवेद्यम) on **Sankasti Chaturthi and Ganesh Chaturthi (संकष्टि चतुर्थी & गणेश चतुर्थी)** celebrations.
**Shree Adi Shankarachrya (आदि शंकराचार्य)** describes about Sweet Dumplings or Modaka  in his **Shree Ganesha Pancharatnam stotra (श्री गणेश पंचरत्नम स्तोत्र).**

> मुदाकरात्त**मोदकं** सदा विमुक्तिसाधकं कलाधरावतंसकं विलासिलोकरक्षकम् ।
>   अनायकैकनायकं विनाशितेभदैत्यकं नताशुभाशुनाशकं नमामि तं विनायकम् ॥१॥
>
> Mudaa-Karaatta-Modakam Sadaa Vimukti-Saadhakam Kalaa-Dhara-Avatamsakam
>   Vilaasi-Loka-Rakssakam | Anaayakai[a-E]ka-Naayakam
>   Vinaashitebha-Daityakam Nata-Ashubha-Ashu-Naashakam Namaami Vinaayakam
>   ||1||
>
> Meaning:
>   1.1: (Salutations to Sri Vinayaka) Who Holds the Divine Joy in His Hand asModaka ( sweet dumpling) and Who Always strives
>   to Accomplish the Liberation of His Devotees towards that Divine Joy,
>   1.2: Who Holds the Digit of the Moon as His Ornament and with a JoyfulSpirit Protects the World,
>   1.3: Who is without any Master but is Himself the only Master for His Devotees, and Protects them by Destroying the (inner) Demons,
>   1.4: To those who Surrender to Him, He Destroys the Inauspicioustendencies Quickly;
>   I Salute Sri Vinayaka and surrender to Him.

More on Ganesh Pancharatnam Stotra -  [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganesha_pancharatnam)

See Full Ganesh Pancharatnam Stotra - [here](http://www.greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/sri_ganesha-ganesha_pancharatnam.php)